Error producing 16-bit silent Wave object with tuneR
I am working in R and need to pad short audio chunks with silence to make then fixed length. I am reading the audio chunks with tuneR::readWave() which indicates the files are 16-bit. I then intended to user tuneR::silence() to create a Wave object of silence of the desired length and then tuneR::bind() to append the silence to the chunk. tuneR::bind() requires the Wave objects to have identical bit depth. The problem is tuneR::silence() is returning the following error when bit is specified as 16.

Error in validObject(.Object) :    invalid class “Wave” object: Float
(non pcm) Wave objects must have a resolution of either 32 or 64 bit

Example code here:
library(tuneR)
padding <- silence(duration = 1, samp.rate = 22050, xunit = "time", bit = 16)

The tuneR documentation indicates that bit=16 is accepted. Is this a bug or have I misunderstood how to use this function. Is there an alternative way to create silence and bind with a Wave object?
thanks
Simon

As mentioned in the error message, you are using float_ieee format. Try pcm format instead: padding <- silence(duration = 1, samp.rate = 22050, xunit = "time", bit = 16,pcm=TRUE)

I think it's just an error in how the man page was written.   silence , along with noise and the other funcs on that page do accept an argument  pcm= {TRUE,FALSE} .  If you set it to TRUE, there's no warnings, for any valid bit size.

One workaround I have found is to create a silent Wave object directy as follows:
sr = 22050
silence_length <- 1.5
silent_samples <- rep(0, sr * silence_length)
padding <- tuneR::Wave(left = silent_samples, bit = 16, samp.rate = sr)

But the original question remains about whether tuneR::silence() with bit=16 should work.
